# Workload identity federation with @google-cloud

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, workload-identity

Does anybody know if there are any other ways of authentication/authorization for access to Google Cloud Storage besides of Service Account key when I use *@google-cloud/storage* Node.js module [from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage)?
I have read about “Workload identity federation”, but it seems for me that I cannot use this approach when I use *@google-cloud/storage* library.
I was not able to find any suitable constructor, only these two:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
var storage = new Storage({
  projectId   : `my_google_project_id`,
  keyFilename : `my_google_key_file.json`   // service account key is inside of this file
});
// or this one:
var storage = new Storage();    // service account key is inside of file specified by environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Any recommendations?
Thank you

Comment: From where do you try to use workload identity federation?

Answer (score 0):

Most Google Clients support a new secrets key file with the type **external_account**. The following demonstrates how to create this file and setup Application Default Credentials (ADC) to load this file.

To use Workload Identity Federation with Google Client libraries, save the federated credentials to a file and then specify that file via the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**. The Storage client will use ADC and locate the credentials from the environment.

**Example for AWS:**

```
# Generate an AWS configuration file.
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config \
    projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/$POOL_ID/providers/$AWS_PROVIDER_ID \
    --service-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
    --aws \
    --output-file /path/to/generated/config.json
```

**Example for Azure:**

```
# Generate an Azure configuration file.
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config \
    projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/$POOL_ID/providers/$AZURE_PROVIDER_ID \
    --service-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
    --azure \
    --output-file /path/to/generated/config.json
```

Note: I generated my credentials on an Azure VM. I added the following command line option to the above command:

```
--app-id-uri=https://iam.googleapis.com/projects/REDACTED/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/pool-azure/providers/provider-id
```

The **output-file** value is used to set the environment:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/generated/config.json
```

The **file** has the following structure. This example is for Azure:

```
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/REDACTED/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/pool-azure/providers/provider-id",
  "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",
  "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
  "credential_source": {
    "url": "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://iam.googleapis.com/projects/REDACTED/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/pool-azure/providers/provider-id",
    "headers": {
      "Metadata": "True"
    },
    "format": {
      "type": "json",
      "subject_token_field_name": "access_token"
    }
  },
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/REDACTED@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken"
}
```

Use this style to create a client:

```
var storage = new Storage();
```

Comment: Thank you.
All you mention is, as far as I understand, "Authenticating as a service account" and described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#windows). And all these require physical file. I don't want to keep service key file as a file. :) I'm looking for a solution where I could pass all these values (which are inside of the file) as parameters to the lib. 
And my application is "totally on premises". no AWS, no Azure, etc.

Comment: @VladimirPimtchenkov - If you are not using AWS or Azure, then what are you using Workload Identity Federation for?

Comment: I'm trying to find out the way to be authorized by Google Cloud Storage without using _service key file_, I thought that Workload Identity Federation would suite my needs.

Comment: I also understand Workload Identity Federation to use ID Tokens, not credential files. I can generate the JWT token I need but how do I use this to authenticate with Google Cloud Storage in my application code?

Comment: @Zaffer - Do not ask new questions in the comments section. Create a new question so that everyone sees the question.